# c# comparing 2 list<object>

Tags: c#

I've got 2 lists of the same object. Now the first list is filled with data from a database table. the other list is filled with data downloaded a server.

Example:

```
public class HistoricData {
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public DateTime Date {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public float Impressions {get;set;}
}
```

So in my object I have the Id property that is unique. Now I need to check if I have objects in my second list that aren't in my first list.
I thought that I could do it in Linq, but I'm a little stuck.

```
var difference = from objHD in objHistoricData
                 join objHDN in objHistoricDataNew on objHD.Id equals objHDN.Id
                 select new {objHDNA = objHDN};
```

This always returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the Except function from LINQ, ans pass the IEqualityComparer that compare the ID.

```
var difference = a.Except( b, new YouEqualitityComparer() )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var difference = objHistoricDataNew.Except(objHistoricDataNew, new HistoricDataComparer());
```

(where `HistoricDataComparer` is a `IEqualityComparer<HistoricData>`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` so that your types are compared by their values rather then by their references.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var difference = list1.Except(list2);
```

But I think [you'll need your own GetHashCode and Equals methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to select all items in objHistoricDataNew that are different, than stored in objHistoricData?

Then maybe something like that:

```
var difference = objhistoricDataNew.Where(objHDN => objHistoricData.Select(objHD => objHD.Id).IndexOf(objHDN.Id) == -1)
```